How turn off vibration effect on banners using NotificationBannerSwift in IOS
I use NotificationBannerSwift for showing banners in swift code:
    let banner = FloatingNotificationBanner(title: messageString,titleFont: UIFont.initFrom(style: .textBody), style: .info, colors: BannerColors())
        banner.duration = 2.0
        banner.transparency = 0.6
banner.show(queuePosition: .back, bannerPosition: .bottom, queue: NotificationBannerQueue(maxBannersOnScreenSimultaneously: 1), edgeInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 100, right: 8), cornerRadius: 10, shadowBlurRadius: 15)

Every banner has vibration effect.
How to switch off this vibration effect?

Which vibration effect are you referring to? https://github.com/Daltron/NotificationBanner/blob/master/NotificationBanner/Assets/floating.gif

This framework automatically adding haptic for vibration try to set none.
    let banner = FloatingNotificationBanner(title: messageString,titleFont: UIFont.initFrom(style: .textBody), style: .info, colors: BannerColors())
        banner.duration = 2.0
        banner.transparency = 0.6
        banner.haptic = .none
        banner.show(queuePosition: .back, bannerPosition: .bottom, queue: NotificationBannerQueue(maxBannersOnScreenSimultaneously: 1), edgeInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 100, right: 8), cornerRadius: 10, shadowBlurRadius: 15)
        

